# How do I write a SELECT IF statement with 2 conditionals?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

so I got this PHP code here:

```
SELECT status , IF(type = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type) . "' , type, '') AS status FROM novacorp.status WHERE type = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type) . "' LIMIT 1;
```

I also want to add another conditional to this so it'll only select status if the info column is also equal to something which I pass using escape string just like shown above.

Same for this statement:

```
UPDATE `novacorp`.`status` SET `status`=". $status ." WHERE `type`='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type) . "';
```

Comment: If you use a *Prepared Statement* your code will be much easier to read. Check out a tutorial to see how.

Comment: Put `case when .. then else .. end` in the SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF(type=whatever AND info=other, valueiftrue, valueiffalse)
```

is probably what you want

Comment: And same thing for the `UPDATE`: `WHERE type=this AND info=that`

Comment: Thanks! How exactly would this statement be thou? With the 2 conditionals: `SELECT status , IF(type = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type) . "' , type, '') AS type FROM novacorp.status WHERE type = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$type) . "' LIMIT 1;`

Comment: That statement is redundant. Since you have already a `WHERE` condition on `type`, the `IF` condition (the same) is always true, so you can simplify it to `SELECT status,type FROM novacorp.status WHERE type='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,type)."' LIMIT 1`. To add another condition, just add ` AND field=value` for instance

Comment: Could you give me the full statement with an added conditional `info='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$additional_info)."'`? Doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: `SELECT status,type FROM novacorp.status WHERE type='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,type)."' AND info='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$additional_info)."' LIMIT 1`